# Angular 4+ HttpClient response Class

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I have an issue where I'm trying to assign a JSON response into a nested typed class.

The types I'm using are as follows

Abstract Resource class:

```
export abstract class JBResource {
    abstract type: string;
    abstract header: string;
    abstract info: string;
}
```

Customer Resource class:

```
import {JBResource} from './jbresource';

export class JBCustomer extends JBResource {
    // Inherited variable
    type = 'Customer';

    get header(): string {
        return this.name;
    }

    get info(): string {
        return this.address1 + ', ' + this.postcode;
    }

    // Own variables
    get id(): number {
        return this.customerid;
    }

    customerid: number;
    name: string;
    address1: string;
    address2: string;
    address3: string;
    address4: string;
    postcode: string;
    phone: string;
    fax: string;
    mobile: string;
    email: string;
    fromemail: string;
    domain: string;
    website: string;
}
```

API Response Class:

```
import {JBResource} from './jbresource';

export class JBAPIResult<T extends JBResource> {
    status: number;
    error: string;
    results: T[];
}
```

I want to call to an API which responds with structured JSON, with a typed get request from the Angular HttpClient, but the result comes out as an untyped object, rather than what I'm expecting:

```
searchResults: JBCustomer[] = [];

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

getCustomers() {
    this.http.post<JBAPIResult<JBCustomer>>('/assets/customersService.php', {
        action: 'search',
    })
        .subscribe(res => {
                console.log('HTTP response', res);
                this.searchResults = res.results;
                console.log('Search Results', this.searchResults);
            }, err => {
                const sbRef = this.snackBar.open('Error getting customers', 'OK');
                console.log('Alert Rule Fetch Error:', err);
            }
        );
}
```

As you can see from the Chrome responses, the object returned is not of APIResponse type, but just a plain Object:

```
{status: 1, search: "%arta%", results: Array(1)}
results: Array(1)
    0:
        address1: "REDACTED, "
        address2: "REDACTED, "
        address3: "REDACTED, "
        address4: "REDACTED"
        customerid: "REDACTED"
        email: "REDACTED"
        fax: "REDACTED"
        mobile: "REDACTED"
        name: "REDACTED"
        phone: "REDACTED"
        postcode: "REDACTED"
        __proto__ :Object
        length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
search: "%arta%"
status: 1
__proto__: Object
```

I understand from browsing previous answers here that applying the  to HttpClient just exposes the interfaces of type T so that you can access them.

How do I actually have the HttpClient parse the result into the class I want, so I can use the accessor methods.

Without actual type casting, what is the point of using HttpClient rather than just HttpClient, since it doesn't actually change the type of the response object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HttpClient Methods not casting response type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066886/angular-httpclient-methods-not-casting-response-type)

Comment: Agreed, it is a partial duplicate of that question, but there is no answer which explains how I would go about mapping the object result onto a defined class.

Comment: The accepted answer does just that.

Comment: I have updated to:

`this.http.post<JBAPIResult<JBCustomer>>('/assets/customersService.php', {
            action: 'search',
            search: this.searchForm.get('search').value
        })
            .map((data) => {
                data.results.map(res => {
                    this.searchResults = res;
                });
            });`

With no effect - If I replace the variable assignment with a console log, it does not trigger

Comment: Nowhere in there do you actually create an instance of the class, though, so it's unclear why that's surprising. If you don't see `new` it's not going to create an instance.

Comment: Using `this.searchResults.push(Object.assign(new JBCustomer(), res));` does nothing either inside the `map`. even `console.log(res)` has no results whatsoever.
This is why I'm saying it does not answer the question. It doesn't say how to go about mapping the resultant data onto a complex class like in my question. The constructor does not take in an arbitrary Object and map it to the class. That is what I need to know.

Comment: More important point. When using `.map()` instead of `.subscribe` the network monitoring show no connection to the url being called

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169957/discussion-between-killer-and-jonrsharpe).

Comment: Please give a [mcve] of that, because I'd expect the object.assign method to successfully create and initialise the instance. If you don't subscribe *anywhere* the request never gets made; that's a separate problem, and is covered in the HttpClient docs.