# rxjs confusion in working with HttpClient

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I am trying to use the typed version of http.get.  How to I get a typed array to add to this.rowData?
The c parameter in the following is an array itself:

```
this.rowData = this.courseProvider.getCourses().map(c => new Course(c));
```

// course.provider.ts

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Api } from '../api/api';
import { Course } from '../../models'

@Injectable()
export class CourseProvider 
{
    course: Course;

    constructor(public api: Api)
    {
    }

    getCourses()    {
        let observable = this.api.get<Course[]>('courses');

        observable.subscribe((courses: Course[]) => {
        }, err => {
            console.error('ERROR', err);

            throw err;
        });

        return observable;
    }
}
```

// course.ts

```
export class CoursePage extends GridPageBase {

    ngOnInit() {
        this.rowData = this.courseProvider.getCourses().map(c => new Course(c));
    }
}
```

// api.ts

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class Api {
    url: string = 'http://192.168.0.2:39049/Services/api';

    get<T>(endpoint: string, params?: any, reqOpts?: any) : Observable<T> {

        if (!reqOpts) 
        {
            reqOpts = this.getHeaders();
        }

        return this.http.get<T>(this.url + '/' + endpoint, {
            headers: reqOpts
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Type hints **do not** cause any casting or conversion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HttpClient Methods not casting response type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066886/angular-httpclient-methods-not-casting-response-type)

Comment: Thanks jonrsharpe for the response.  How do I achieve a typed array?  I've tried the rxjs map operator with no success as well.

Comment: So give a [mcve] of that, *"with no success"* isn't a very specific problem.

Comment: the above code is wrapped in a function called getCourses.  Calling code is as such:

    this.rowData = this.courseProvider.getCourses().map(c => new Course(c));

c is an array, not a single instance.

Comment: [Edit] the question. And as Course doesn't have a constructor it's unclear why you'd expect that to work. You also seem to be confusing mapping an array and mapping an observable.

Comment: Sorry I'm being confusing.  I had it there before.